# Обновление версии php

Tags: php, apache2

Друзья, всем привет! На производстве стоит сервер Apache версии 2.2.22 и php 5.3.10 . Подскажите пожалуйста, будут ли последствия в работе веб-приложений, если я обновлю php до 7.0.30 ? Можно ли обойтись без последствий и совместима ли эта версия с данной версией Apache ? Цена ошибки очень велика, стоит ли обновлять или оставить как есть? Скорее всего много функций не будут работать в новой версии php. Как поступить? Нужен ваш профессиональный совет.

Comment: Если "цена ошибки очень велика", то делайте пробный апгрейд на тестовом сервере. Или действуйте по правилу: "Работает - не трожь!"

Comment: Нет, не будет работать. Сперва запустите полностью аналогичный сервер в виртуальной машине (а если деньги есть, то лучше купить второй настоящий сервер). Потом обновитесь до новых версий внутри этой виртуальной машины, не трогая настоящий сервер. Потом разберитесь со всеми ошибками в виртуалке и проведите полное тестирование. Потом изучите средства автоматизации развёртывания (Ansible, Docker и т.п.), автоматически выкатите сайт в виртуалку и протестируйте всё ещё раз. *И только после всего этого* приступайте к выкатыванию обновлений на настоящий сервер.

Comment: спасибо за советы.

Comment: Есть инструменты, которые проверяют совместимость кода статическим анализом

https://github.com/gisostallenberg/php-to-7-aid

https://github.com/Alexia/php7mar

https://github.com/sstalle/php7cc

https://github.com/etsy/phan